# Copying weights from one Conv2D layer to another

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

### Context

I have trained a model on MNIST using Keras. My goal is to print images after the first layer with the first layer being a `Conv2D` layer. To go about this I'm creating a new model with a single `Conv2D` layer in which I'll copy the weights from the trained network into the new one.

```
# Visualization for image ofter first convolution
model_temp = Sequential()
model_temp.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                         activation='relu', 
                         input_shape=(28,28,1,)))

trained_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]

model_temp.layers[0].set_weights(trained_weights)

activations = model_temp._predict(X_test)
```

The variable `model` holds the trained data from the full network. Also, the input parameters to `Conv2D` are exactly the same as the ones in the original model.

I have checked the shape of both the weights for `model` and `model_temp` and both return as `(3, 3, 1, 32)`. In theory I should be able to get the weights from the original and input them directly into the `set_weights()` call on the single `Conv2D` layer in the new model.

After this convolution, variable named 'activations' would be a tensor that holds 32 (layers), 26 by 26 matrices of output values for each input image.

---

### Error

So when I run this code, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-4ae260f0fe89> in <module>()
      7 trained_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
      8 print(trained_weights.shape)
----> 9 model_test = model_test.layers[0].set_weights(trained_weights)
     10 
     11 activations = model_test._predict(X_test[1, 28, 28, 1])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in set_weights(self, weights)
   1189                              str(len(params)) +
   1190                              ' weights. Provided weights: ' +
-> 1191                              str(weights)[:50] + '...')
   1192         if not params:
   1193             return

ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "conv2d_60" with a  weight list of length 3, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. Provided weights: [[[[ -6.22274876e-01  -2.18614027e-01   5.29607059...
```

On the last line, why is `set_weights(weights)` looking for a length of two instead of three? This error message is slightly cryptic to me so if not a length of two what does "expecting two weights" mean?

Also i'm open to suggestions on an easier way to go about this.

---

### After Further Investigation

After inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py) for `get_weights()` (line 1168), the error is raised in this section:

```
 params = self.weights
    if len(params) != len(weights):
        raise ValueError('You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "' +
                         self.name +
                         '" with a  weight list of length ' +
                         str(len(weights)) +
                         ', but the layer was expecting ' +
                         str(len(params)) +
                         ' weights. Provided weights: ' +
                         str(weights)[:50] + '...')
```

This condition check determines if the length of what I passed in (the `(3, 3, 1, 32)` tensor from above) is equivalent to the weights property of this class. So I tested these properties as follows:

```
# Print contents of weights property
print(model.layers[0].weights)
print(model_test.layers[0].weights)

# Length test of tensors from get_weights call
len_test  = len(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0])
len_test2 = len(model_test.layers[0].get_weights()[0])
print("\nLength get_weights():")
print("Trained Model: ", len_test, "Test Model: ", len_test2)

# Length test of wights attributes from both models
len_test3 = len(model.layers[0].weights)
len_test4 = len(model_test.layers[0].weights)
print("\nLength weights attribute:")
print("Trained Model: ", len_test3, "Test Model: ", len_test4)
```

Output:

```
[<tf.Variable 'conv2d_17/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32_ref>,         <tf.Variable 'conv2d_17/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>]
[<tf.Variable 'conv2d_97/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_97/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>]

Length get_weights():
('Trained Model: ', 3, 'Test Model: ', 3)

Length weights attribute:
('Trained Model: ', 2, 'Test Model: ', 2)
```

This output makes one hundred percent sense to me as these convolutions in each model are constructed exactly the same. It's also now obvious why it wants a length of two. This is because the weights property is a list of two elements of `tf.Variable`.

Further investigating this source file, at line 213 we see that weights holds "The concatenation of the lists trainable_weights and non_trainable_weights (in this order)".

So then sure I can grab the weights attribute from the `Conv2D` layer of the original trained model and pass that in to satisfy this condition but then this condition isn't checking the shape of the passed in data at all. If I do pass in weights from my original model I get a `setting an array element with a sequence` error from numpy.

### Thoughts

I think this is a bug in the source code. I would be awesome if someone could verify this.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting about bias vectors. Get_weights() and set_weights() functions for conv2d returns a list with weights matrix as first element and bias vector as second. So the error rightly suggests it expects a list with 2 members. Doing the following should thus work

```
trained_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()
model_temp.layers[0].set_weights(trained_weights)
```

Also if you want to get output from an intermediate layer you dont need to manually transfer weights. Doing something like following is much more convenieant

```
get_layer_output = K.function([model.input],
                                  [model.layers[0].output])
layer_output = get_layer_output([x])[0]
```

or

```
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```